# Cassandra 3.x on Kubernetes 1.2-release (5 cassandra nodes)

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

Has anyone been able to get cassandra 3.x running on kubernetes?

cassandra 2.1.13 runs great but 3.3 is have trouble talking to other cassandra nodes.  My yamls are the same except for the container.  I just upgraded gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v8 from 2.1.13 to 3.3

Is there a new setting in 3.x that I need to config differently then 2.1?

Running nodetool status on all the 5 nodes show they see each other and have a status/state of UN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are two additional port that need to be open for the containers to talk to each other

7000 and 7001

All better.